# Calling help in SAS to refer syntax and arguments of a function

Tags: sas

I am usually an R user also wanting to familiarize myself with SAS. Whenever we need to refer the documentation or examples for a function in `R` in the R-Studio IDE we use `?xxxxx`. I was wondering if there is something similar to this in `SAS` too. I am using the SAS University Edition.

Comment: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#onlinedoc.htm - see the section on 'Getting Help from the Command Bar' - not sure if this applies to the Uni Edition

Comment: Not as easily, partly because its not a command line interface, partly different language structure.  If you use the University Edition, use the SAS 9.4 online help. I specifically like the Syntax Index: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/syntaxidx/67925/HTML/default/index.htm#/documentation/cdl/en/syntaxidx/67925/HTML/default/shared/start.htm

Comment: Thanks ! both comments very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS Studio, the browser-based interface for SAS University Edition, has code suggestions, so you can start typing a function name and a bubble will appear containing the function arguments and brief descriptions. If I recall, the bubble also has a link to the full documentation for the function in the SAS online documentation.

In most other situations, your best bet is to just go directly from the online docs. They're very thorough.